# How can I adjust the cvtColor grayscale function so that it keeps a dimension for RGB

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tensorflow

function: cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

If I input a 32x32x3 image (3 for R/G/B) it will output a 32x32 image. However, I need it to return a 32x32x1 image instead so that I can use it for tensorflow. How do I adjust the function?

Comment: Hi, 
The 32x32 IS a 1 bit depth image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TensorFlow, you can convert the 32x32 matrix to a 32x32x1 tensor using the [`tf.expand_dims(img, 2)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#expand_dims) operation or the TensorFlow indexing operator:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_tensor = tf.constant(img)
img_expanded = tf.expand_dims(img, 2)  # or `img[:, :, tf.newaxis]`
```

The same can be achieved using NumPy indexing:

```
import numpy as np
# ...
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_expanded = img[:, :, np.newaxis]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing the grayscale conversion in the preprocessing step so I don't want to involve tf yet. Is there another way to do it without tf?

Comment: Sure, you can do it in NumPy in much the same way (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_expanded = img[np.newaxis,:, :, np.newaxis]
```

This also works